# Custom policy auth in ASPNET Core 2 (jwt auth)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-authorization

I have a simple app (API) that uses JWT auth. I have implemented a way to check if the token is still valid based on some info in the DB. It looks something like this ->

```
        //Check if the token is valid
        var tokenStamp = int.Parse(claimsIdentity.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat)?.Value);
        if (userDto.PasswordChangedAt > tokenStamp)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("SessionExpired", "Please relog.");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        //Done checking token
```

I've been trying for hours to move this code up to a policy so instead of writing all that i could have something like

```
[Authorize(Policy="MYPOLICY")]
```

My problem here is that i need to get info from the SQL DB (as stated above) to do the check and pretty much everything ive searched for online was just a simple "age verifier" with static data.

I've tried some things, but i probably just made a mess (still kinda new to netcore). Here goes nothing ->

```
public class TokenValidationAuthorizeAttribute : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public void TokenChangeValidation(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserService userService)
    {
        //var claimsIdentity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var tokenCreationDate = int.Parse(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat).Value);
        var userId = int.Parse(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value);
        var user = userService.GetById(userId, false);
        var userInfo = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
        var tokenStamp = int.Parse(context.User.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat)?.Value);

        TokenIssuedAt = tokenStamp;


    }

    public int TokenIssuedAt { get; set; }

    internal IAuthorizationRequirement TokenChangeValidation(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TokenValidationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TokenValidationAuthorizeAttribute>
{

    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "TokenValidation";
    private IUserService _userService;

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,TokenValidationAuthorizeAttribute requirement)
    {
        var userService = _userService;

        //var claimsIdentity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var tokenCreationDate = int.Parse(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat).Value);
        var userId = int.Parse(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value);
        var user = userService.GetById(userId, false);
        var userInfo = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
        var tokenStamp = int.Parse(context.User.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat)?.Value);

        if (userInfo.PasswordChangedAt >= requirement.TokenIssuedAt)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

But i can in no way create a new instance of the TokenValidationAuthorizeAttribute since i can't pass the context from ConfigureServices so the following bit of code surely doesnt work.

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("TokenOk", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenValidationAuthorizeAttribute()));
        });
```

Any tip to push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to have duplicated logic of token-checking both in `AuthorizationRequirement` and `AuthorizationHandler` .

Just create a dummy authorization requirement that has nothing inside :

```
public class TokenValidationAuthorizeAttribute : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    // remove codes here
}
```

And Use `DependencyInjection` to ask for a `IUserService` :

```
public class TokenValidationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TokenValidationAuthorizeAttribute>
{
    private IUserService _userService;

    public TokenValidationHandler(IUserService userService) {
        this._userService = userService;
    }

    // ...

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TokenValidationAuthorizeAttribute requirement)
    {
         // check the token-code of current user against the one from db here ...

         // the toekn-code of current user
         var claimsIdentity = context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
         var tokenCreationDate = int.Parse(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat).Value);

         // ...

    }
}
```

To make the ASP.NET Core realize it should check the handler , we also need to add a authorization configuration :

```
services.AddAuthorization(opts=>
{
    opts.AddPolicy("TokenOk", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenValidationAuthorizeAttribute()));
});
```

Lastly , don't forget to register the authorization handler and the IUserService  :

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler,TokenValidationHandler>();
services.AddScoped<IUserService,YourUserServiceImplementation>();
```

Now , protect the action you want to validate `TokenOk` with `[Authorize("TokenOk")]` , it will work as expected .

Comment: After checking if my token is fine (userInfo.PasswordChangedAt <= tokenStamp) i'm giving it "context.Succeed(requirement)". The "requirement" is actually empty. It does work, but shouldnt i give it something there? (as a best practice, cause i assume it isnt a security problem). Also, everything works, but there's one thing that i needed to change from your code ->             services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, TokenValidationHandler>();

Due to my other dependant classes (DataContext,DbOptions etc) i had to switch to scoped (or transient). I assume scoped is fine? (still learning)

Comment: Damn these comments i can't write a long one. I'd appreciate if you've got the time to answer my 2 little questions above, either way, done some tests and with scoped it works perfectly. One more thing...is there a way for me to customize the error message ? (currently throwing Forbidden, i'd like to be able to customize it). Many thanks !

Comment: @DanteR. 1. Requirements are dummy classes to hold information that will be processed by authorization handler . If there's no extra data , it will be OK to keep them empty .  2 .You're right . I didn't realize I should use Scoped Service because the the `IAuthorizationHandler` will have a dependency on `DbContext` .

Comment: @DanteR. As for custom error message , one approach is to create a middleware which will detect a `Forbid` result and then replace it with a new one or redirect to another page .

Comment: Got it, many thanks. One more thing if i may. If i'd create another policy (lets say i'd copy paste the one above), i could add [Authorize("TokenOk", "MyNewPolicy")] to use them both ? Asking this in case i'll create more policies in the future (i'd rather keep them separate to easily modify whichever i need).

Comment: @DanteR. You're free to combine all kinds of policies  like `and`: `[Authorize("policy1"),Authorize("policy2")]`,

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Virtual beer to you sir.